# How to retrieve the correct Account records from SOQL query?

Tags: soql, query, date

In account record I have a custom `myDate__c` field  of type date.

I need to retrieve all Account records where `myDate__c` is older than 45 days.

I've tried with the following query:

```
SELECT id, name 
FROM Account 
WHERE myDate__c <= today() - 45
```

However I received a warning message:

> Date and number are incompatible types

How to change my query to retrieve the correct Account records?

I need only SOQL. No Apex.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I recommend you read up on [Date Formats and Date Literals](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_dateformats.htm) in the **`SOQL and SOSL Reference`**. This resource covers several ways you can format date fields that you may find useful in the future. Specifically for your current use case:

> **Date Literal**
> LAST_N_DAYS:n
>
> **Range**
> For the number n provided, starts 00:00:00 of the current day and continues for the past n days.
>
> **Example**
> SELECT Id FROM Account WHERE CreatedDate = LAST_N_DAYS:365